# How to access files remotely in asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net

I am making a website in asp.net using c# and sql server 2008. 
I made one web form in which there are two buttons, on first button click ,i select a excel file from my computer drive. and on second button click ,,the whole file data is copied to sql server table.
this works fine. but i want to know how can i load and saved that file in databse table, if i want to access that website from another system. how to access that system files  remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Save that Excel file on the server

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/AppFolderName/" + FileName));
```

and then later on you will able to access the same file from any where from `application server`

Answer (score 0):

You have to upload that file on server first in order to access it. you can do it by Fileeupload control and `HttpPostedFile`